# Linq - return index of collection using conditional logic

Tags: linq

I have a collection

```
List<int> periods = new List<int>();
            periods.Add(0);
            periods.Add(30);
            periods.Add(60);
            periods.Add(90);
            periods.Add(120);
            periods.Add(180);

            var overDueDays = 31;
```

I have a variable over due days. When the vale is between 0 to 29 then I want to return the index of 0. When between 30 - 59 I want to return index 1. The periods list is from db so its not hard coded and values can  be different from what are here. What is the best way to to it using LINQ in one statement.

Comment: Do you actually mean index 1 instead of 2?

Comment: Then I'd just divide by 30 and take the floor of that (plus some safety checks probably).

Answer (score 0):

It's not really what Linq is designed for, but (assuming that the range is not fixed) you could do the following to get the index

```
List<int> periods = new List<int>();
            periods.Add(0);
            periods.Add(30);
            periods.Add(60);
            periods.Add(90);
            periods.Add(120);
            periods.Add(180);

var overDueDays = 31;

var result = periods.IndexOf(periods.First(n => overDueDays < n)) - 1;
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to add an edit comment.  Added the "- 1" after re-reading your question so that it gets the right index

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.TakeWhile()`:

```
int periodIndex = periods.TakeWhile(p => p <= overDueDays).Count() - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this ?

```
    var qPeriods = periods.Where(v => v <= overDueDays)
                          .Select((result, i) => new { index = i })
                          .Last();
```

Comment: The use of `Where` this way will alter the original indices since you will have less items than you started with whenever that condition is met.

Comment: I thought that as well but I would assume if the periods are `sorted` from the OP question.

Comment: I misread your `Where` condition. My original statement would apply if it was `overDueDays < v` but you've set it up differently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `periods` is sorted, you can use the following approach:

```
var result = periods.Skip(1)
                    .Select((o, i) => new { Index = i, Value = o })
                    .FirstOrDefault(o => overDueDays < o.Value);

if (result != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Index);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Matching range not found!");
}
```

The first value is skipped since we're interested in comparing with the upper value of the range. By skipping it, the indices fall into place without the need to subtract 1. `FirstOrDefault` is used in case `overDueDays` doesn't fall between any of the available ranges.